# I have 5 images and i want to set these as src of single ImageButton. Each time on click it should change and it must retain its value if app closes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Its like a fan regulator everytime image (src should be of ImageButton)should change on click and retain its value if app closes.
What should be the best way ?
i want to use just one java file

**GLOBAL VAR count = 0;**

**In onCreate**

```
aButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int f = sharedPreferences.getInt("count_key", count);
if (count == 0) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0);
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg1);
    }
    if (count == 2) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg2);
    }
    if (count == 3) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg3);
    }
    if (count == 4) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg4);
    }
```

**Then **

```
    aButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int f = sharedPreferences.getInt("clicked4", count);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            if (count<5) {
                if (count == 1) {
                    toggleSound.start();
                    aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg1);
                    editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                if (count == 2) {
                    toggleSound.start();
                    aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg2);
                    editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                if (count == 3) {
                    toggleSound.start();
                    aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg3);
                    editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                if (count == 4) {
                    toggleSound.start();
                    aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg4);
                    editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
                toggleSound.start();
                aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0);
                editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Store the last value of image button in shared preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd do it this way :

**private int Clicks;**

**public class .... extends .... implements View.OnClickListener**

Then in your OnCreate

**aButton4.setOnClickListener(this);**

Inside the onClickListener method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Clicks++;
        switch (Clicks)
        {
            case 1:
                aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0);
                toggleSound.start();
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                editor.commit();
            case 2:
                aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg1);
                toggleSound.start();
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("clicked4", count);
                editor.commit();
            case 3:
                ....
            case 4:
                ....
                Clicks =0;
       }
```

**EDIT: In your onCreate code, do next**

```
aButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int f = sharedPreferences.getInt("count_key", count);
if (f== 0) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0);
    }
    if (f== 1) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg1);
    }
    if (f== 2) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg2);
    }
    if (f== 3) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg3);
    }
    if (f== 4) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg4);
    }
```

Comment: the problem is its not saving its state, when the app closes it resets to default image....i am updating my code kindly check it

Comment: i think i see the mistake, you define count as an int and call it in your onCreate for showing image, so it will always show the default given integer. change this : 'int f = sharedPreferences.getInt("count_key", count);
if (count == 0) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0);
    }' **to this** 'int f = sharedPreferences.getInt("count_key", 1); "the value you want, default int value"
if (f == 0) {
        aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0);
    }'

Comment: but why are you assigning 1 to count_key
and this int count is just for condition checking, so why it doesn't work ?

Comment: you aren't assigning 1 to count_key, if the sharedpreferences doesn't find count_key, it will take the default value which in your case is count? So in your onCreate, the default value for count is that which you set on top (private int count = ...

Comment: From android developers, [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) **public abstract int getInt (String key, int defValue)
Added in API level 1

Retrieve an int value from the preferences.
Parameters
key  String: The name of the preference to retrieve.
defValue  int: Value to return if this preference does not exist.
Returns
int  Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int.**

Comment: i have 5 images, which much switch after each click. take the example of fan regulator

Comment: if i use
'int f = sharedPreferences.getInt("count_key", 1); "the value you want, default int value" if (f == 0) { aButton4.setImageResource(R.drawable.reg0); }'

i won't be able to switch between 5 images

Comment: oh, you will, because the sharedpreferences is going to seek after count_key, it finds it with an value and return that value. If the sharedpreferences doesn't find count_key, it will give the default value, in your case, count

Comment: so what exactly i should change in my code to get proper functioning of my task

Comment: so what exactly i should change in my code to get proper functioning of my task

Comment: if you can help me on this another question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772102/usage-of-gif-in-imagebutton?noredirect=1#comment59215863_35772102

that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Set an onClickListener.  Have the onClickListener set a new source.  Write the value of the source to shared preferences so its saved.  In your Activity's onCreate, read the shared preference to find out what to set it to initially.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit ?
I am new to android

Comment: Then I'd google for a few of those terms and learn.  Try OnClickListener, sharedPreferences, and the Activity lifecycle (which onCreate is part of).

Comment: i wrote the whole code and now just one problem is occurring. When i restart the app it image resets to its default src which is reg0.
 Please checkout the updated program

Answer (score 0):

This is logic kind of question, and below answer will not work if you simply copy and paste, you have to write code to get below code executed.

```
int count_Global_Declar =0;

SharedPreferences.Editor soteCount= getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

button.setOnclickList(.... View view){
bla bla...


if(count <=5){
count = count+1;
soteCount= .putInt("count_key", count_Global_Declar ).commit();
storeCount.
    ifcount_Global_Declar  == 1){
    //First image source
    } 
    if(count_Global_Declar  ==2){
    //Secound image source
    }

    if(count_Global_Declar  ==3){
    // Third image source
    }

    .... So on .,
}else{
count_Global_Declar = 0;
soteCount= .putInt("count_key", count_Global_Declar );
}
)};

onStart(){
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
count_Global_Declar =  prefs.getInt("count_key", 0);
}
```

Comment: what's that soteCount doing in below if(<=5). sytntax for putINT ?

Comment: Try it yourself and post your error if you have, and this bolg is meant for sharing the knowledge not to spoon feed the developers. Thanks.

Comment: i wrote the whole code and now just one problem is occurring. When i restart the app it image resets to its default src which is reg0.
 Please checkout the updated program

Comment: get the stored sharedP values from onStart method, i just modified the code. accept the answer if it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: you assigned 0 to "count_key" in onStart()
that will select default image that is reg0